# error in midlet while implementing command

Tags: java-me, command, lwuit, midlet

import com.sun.lwuit.Command;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

in my code but still the following errors are coming...

```
exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 2);  //line 1
 textbox.addCommand(exitCommand);                     //line 2
```

Command.EXIT cannot be resolved..

The method `addCommand(Command)` in the type Displayable is not applicable for the arguments (Command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no constructor to pass like this. Try to learn LWUIT and see this [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/)for your reference. You can't use LWUIT command for J2me textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing LWUIT Commands, but using the LCUID Command methods. Your code would be right if you were importing `javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;`. But if you want to use LWUIT components, you have to forget about Items and moreover Item Commands.

I don't know if it's agood idea to mix LCUID and LWUIT, but well, I haven't used it, so I can't really say.